# Why do I get a compilation error when I try to have two methods with the same name and parameter type?

Tags: java

If i change the `byte` to `int` I get a compiler error. Could you explain the problem?

```
public class A {
   protected int xy(int x) { return 0; }
}

class B extends A {
   protected long xy(int x) { return 0; } //this gives compilor error
   //protected long xy(byte x) { return 0; } // this works fine
}
```

Comment: Because the method signature of `A.xy` is the same as `B.xy`: same name, same amount of parameters and same type of parameters.

Comment: Your methods as they are posted in the text are absolutely fine because they have **different** parameter types. `int` is **not** the same as `byte`

Comment: @GermannArlington: If you just read the title and code, it's a bit confusing, but the opening line of the *question* makes it clear: *"f i change the byte to int I get a compiler error."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If i change the `byte` to `int` I get a compiler error.

If you do that, you have this:

```
public class A {
   protected int xy(int x) { return 0; }
}

class B extends A {
   protected long xy(int x) { return 0; }
}
```

...and the only difference in the `xy` methods is their return type. Methods cannot be differentiated solely by their return types, that's the way Java is defined. Consider this:

```
myInstance.xy(1);
```

Which `xy` should that call? `long xy(int x)` or `int xy(int x)`?

If your goal is to *override* `xy` in `B`, then you need to make its return type `int` in order to match `A#xy`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two methods with same signature in a Class though the methods are placed separately in different classes in the same inheritance tree. i.e. Base class and sub class

Note : Just return types can't make the compiler understand the difference in methods. return type is **NOT** included in the method signature as well

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write two methods with the same name and input parameters, that is not possible.

Look at the following two methods:

```
float met(){
  return 4.5;
}

double met(){
  return 5.4;
}
```

If we would write this line then

```
int x = (int)met();
```

what method would be called?

It is not possible to decide, therefore this situation is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

That's because if You change byte to int You will have method with the same signature in base and sub class (same method name and parameter type) and therefore return type should be the same as well. Because is not (int and long) it will give You error

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate methods by parameters and names only.

```
     both methods are in same class B

     b.xy(byte x) or b.xy(int x) is called for input xy(0) or xy(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Overiding method should return a type that can be substituted for the type returned by overriden method

Answer (score 0):

Because when you change the `byte` into `int` the Instance which calls the method doesn't know which method is meant. The overwritten one or the old one?

Thats why it's not allowed to have the same signatures (method name, type of parameters and amount of parameters). Just as an information: The return type is not part of the signature.